# FlashBuilder: How to get file location from FileReference object?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

How can I browse to a file and send file location to the backend using FileReference object?
I am using flex 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security purposes; you cannot get the file location using FileReference in a browser based app; you can only get the file name.

Comment: Then is there any way to get file location?

Comment: Not in a browser based application.  You can get a FileReference to the object with user input using the browse() method.  In an AIR Application you can use the File class.  @MaheshParate Nothing done on the server can provide the location of the file on the client machine.

Comment: @MaheshParate Do you mean that I go to server side with File object and then get FileLocation from java code? Can you please provide URL to sample code?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, I have deleting my previous comment. Thanks @Flextras for pointing me in right direction. I am providing some link hope they may help in some respect….… http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81104-how-to-upload-file-from-flex-in-back-end-with-spring-blazeds and http://www.pavlasek.sk/devel/?p=10